# How can I use a related field in a SlugRelatedField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following structures

```
class State(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ....

class ReviewState(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    state = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=ReviewState.objects.all(), slug_field='state__label', required=False)
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = [
        'id',
        'state', # this points to a ReviewState object
        ....
      ]
```

What I'm trying to do is using the State object's label as the field instead. But it doesn't seem like djangorestframework likes the idea of using `__` to lookup slug fields. Would it be possible to do this? If it was:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    state = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=State.objects.all(), slug_field='label', required=False)
```

that would be no problem, but I'm trying to use the ReviewState instead. I'm also trying to avoid having a ReviewStateSerializer as the resulting json would look like this

```
{...
'state': {'state': 'Pending'}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, and well put.

Using `SlugRelatedField('state__label', queryset=...)` works fine, with 1 caveat: its just calling `queryset.get(state__label="x")` which errors if there isn't **exactly** 1 match.

**1) Write a custom field?**

Inherit from `SlugRelatedField` and override `to_internal_value()`, maybe by calling `.first()` instead of `.get()`, or whatever other logic you need.

**2) Re-evaluate this relationship, maybe its 1-to-1? a choice field?**

I'm a bit confused on how this would all work, since you can have a "1 to many" with `State` => `ReviewState`.  The default lookup (if you don't do #1) will throw an error when multiple matches occur.

Maybe this is a 1-to-1 situation with the model?  Perhaps the ReviewState can use a `ChoiceField` instead of a table of states?

Perhaps the 'label' can be the PK of the `State` table, and also a `SlugField` rather than a non-unique `CharField`?

**3) Write different serializers for the `List` and `Create` cases**

DRF doesn't give us a built-in way to do this, but this reliance on "one serializer to do it all" is the cause of a lot of problems I see on SO.  Its just really hard to get what you want without having different serializers for different cases.  It's not hard to roll-your-own mixin to do it, but here's an example which uses an override:

```
from rest_framework import serializers as s

class MyCreateSerializer(s.ModelSerializer):
    state = s.SlugRelatedField(...)
    ...

class MyListSerializer(s.ModelSerializer):
    # use dotted notation, serializers read *object* attributes
    state = s.CharField(source="state.state.label")
    ...

class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.select_related('state__state')
    ...
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return MyCreateSerializer
        else:
            return MyListSerializer
```

Comment: the double underscore notation didn't work for me.  I have a TeamMember model that is a profile extension of the User model (one-to-one).  The natural_key for TeamMember is "user__username" (and that works fine).  I now have a Task model with a ForeignKey field of team_member (to TeamMember model).  In the serializer, I defined the SlugRelatedField with slug_field="user__username" (and also tried "user.username" and just "username"), but I get "'TeamMember' object has no attribute 'user__username'."